# Python 2.7 successfully imports tensorflow, but python 3.6.4 throws error while importing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, python-3.6, rasa-nlu

I am able to import tensorflow using python 2.7. But I am getting the following error while trying to import tensorflow using python 3.6.4:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have cuda 9.1 and tensorflow 1.6 installed in my system.

Comment: `cuda9.1` is not supported by `tensorflow 1.6`. you have to install  `cuda9.0 `or compile `tensorflow` with `cuda 9.1` from source

Answer (score 1):

> ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

It seems your Tensorflow version for Python 3.6.x has been compiled for CUDA 9.0, not 9.1.

So far for CUDA 9.1, you may have to build Tensorflow from source yourself ([Github discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15656), [install doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)).